# One table only getting scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping

Im scraping this website and getting the results I want.  However I can only get the frst table and not all the tables.  Cannot figure out how to get the other tables to pull?????

```
url='https://www.rootsandrain.com/event4493/2017-aug-26-uci-world-cup-dh-7-val-di-sole/results/'
response = requests.get(url)
  

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'list'})
headers = [heading.text for heading in table.find_all('th')]
response = requests.get(url)
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

> However I can only get the frst table and not all the tables. Cannot
> figure out how to get the other tables to pull?????

You are using `find` which does find 1st described element, use `find_all` to get itertable of all matching elements, please try following snippets

```
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'list'})
headers = [heading.text for heading in table.find_all('th')]
print(headers)
```

and

```
for table in soup.find_all('table', {'class':'list'}):
    headers = [heading.text for heading in table.find_all('th')]
    print(headers)
```

Comment: 'C:/Users/Tim/OneDrive/Documents/Python Scripts')
  File "C:\Users\Tim\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\mtb fantasy.py", line 69
    for table in soup.find_all('table',{'class':'list'})
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: @THough I fixed my code snippet